# How to estimate density given similar instances?

Tags: distributions, density-estimation

I'm trying to estimate the probability distribution of a random variable $X$ given values of $N$ parameters/qualities $Q_1, Q_2, ..., Q_N$, and historical data.

The two extremes in estimation would be:

1. overfitting by estimating the distribution of $X | \{ Q_1
       = q_1, Q_2 = q_2, ..., Q_N = q_n \}$
2. conditioning with minimal information, e.g. $X | Q_1 <=
       q_1$

The first option would result in overfitting or might not even have any data points for estimation, whereas the second case would yield a very inaccurate estimate with a lot of room for improvement.

-

Is there a way to combine information from multiple estimates while avoiding overfitting?

More specifically, let's say that you are trying to estimate the distribution of $X | \{ Q_1
    < q_1, Q_2 < q_2, Q_3 < q_3 \}$ by combining the density estimates of $X | \ Q_1 < q_1$, $X | \ Q_2 < q_2$, and $X | \ Q_3 < q_3$. What is the optimal way to do this given that the qualities can be correlated, i.e. that, for example, $P(Q_1 < q_1) < P(Q_1 < q_1 | Q_2 < q_2)$?

(You don't necessarily need to give a complete answer. Even pointing to relevant literature would be helpful.)

Comment: For the overfit scenario, have you considered looking into simplifying assumptions such as naiive Bayes?